# How to i generate serenity reports with jbehave when migrated from thucydides

Tags: serenity-bdd

Is there any document to generate reports in serenity we migrated from thucydides but still reports are generating in thucydides in jenkins, i found this plugin in google https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Serenity+Plugin can i use this or is there any other way.

Thanksinadvance

Answer (score 0):

The https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Serenity+Plugin is unrelated to Serenity BDD. Serenity is simple the new name for Thucydides, so there is no "migration" as such. Reports are (by default) generated in the `target\site\serenity` directory, and can be published like any other HTML report in Jenkins.

In more recent versions of Jenkins, the default security configuration breaks most non-trival HTML reports, and needs to be reconfigured to display the reports correctly: see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy